# Rounding Int from Decimal C#

Tags: c#, decimal, rounding, long-integer, division

I'm having a hard time understand the process of rounding when I convert a decimal to a long.

For example

```
decimal pi = Convert.ToDecimal(Math.PI);
long d = 2534254324524352;
long dpi = Convert.ToInt64(pi * Convert.ToDecimal(d));
//I'd like to do the reverse to get the value of d as dd
long dd = Convert.ToInt64(Convert.ToDecimal(dpi) /pi);
```

In this particular example it works but sometimes when I try to get to number back it doesn't work. When you convert a decimal to a long is there an exact way it's rounded? Is there a way to control that behavior?

Thanks

Comment: "it doesn't work" isn't really helpful. Please find a short but complete example which *does* demonstrate the problem, stating the expected behaviour and the actual behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Convert.ToInt64`, like most default conversion methods, uses [banker's rounding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even), i.e. rounding to the nearest multiple of two. [Here's a demo](http://ideone.com/7UmPP) - both 6.5 and 5.5 are rounded to 6.

```
Console.WriteLine("Rounding 5.5 to {0}", Convert.ToInt64(5.5D)); // 6
Console.WriteLine("Rounding 6.5 to {0}", Convert.ToInt64(6.5D)); // 6
```

You can change this behaviour by using `Math.Floor` or `Math.Ceil` on a `decimal` before converting it to a `long`, [as seen here](http://ideone.com/cGEKY). `Math.Floor` is probably what you need.

```
Console.WriteLine("Rounding 5.5 to {0}", Convert.ToInt64(Math.Floor(5.5D))); // 5
Console.WriteLine("Rounding 6.5 to {0}", Convert.ToInt64(Math.Floor(6.5D))); // 6
```

So:

```
decimal pi = Convert.ToDecimal(Math.PI);
long d = 2534254324524352;
long dpi = Convert.ToInt64(Math.Floor(pi * Convert.ToDecimal(d)));
long dd = Convert.ToInt64(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDecimal(dpi) / pi));
```